# How to talk to Cardano blockchain using Javascript

Tags: cardano-cli, javascript

How would I go about making a Javascript script which can get information from the cardano blockchain. Like what library or framework can I use.

Answer (score 4):

While I have not used this API myself, the [Blockfrost API](https://blockfrost.io/) has a [JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/blockfrost/blockfrost-js) that can do that. There is a free tier.

Answer (score 3):

[Ogmios](https://github.com/CardanoSolutions/ogmios) runs alongside a cardano node and provides a websocket api to sync or query the chain. Documentation is [available here](https://ogmios.dev/). If you don't want to host the node yourself, or want to get up and runnning as quickly as possible, you could check out [the instance hosted by Gimbalabs](https://gimbalabs.com/dandelionapis/ogmios-api)

Answer (score 1):

Nami wallet injects a bunch of functions yo your browser, similar to meta mask:

https://namiwallet.io/

Answer (score 1):

The [MESH JS SDK](https://meshjs.dev) is ideally suited for Javascript or Typescript interaction with Cardano, including functions abstracting most of the core functionality and "Providers" which can be used to get data from Blockfrost, Koios, Ogmios etc. There are also React elements, and starter kits and basic templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can also interact with cardano blockchain via cli, and there is a nice library that i use personally a lot named [cardanocli-js](https://github.com/Berry-Pool/cardanocli-js)